# Bug in checking positive integer N for power of 2 with large N

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have this program to check if a no is power of 2 or not, but it's not working on a test case if `no = 1099511627776`:

```
int not; // no of testcase
unsigned long long int no; // input number
int arr[100];
scanf ("%d", &not);

for ( int i = 0; i < not; i++ )
{
    scanf ("%llu", &no);
    if ( no & !(no & (no - 1))) // check wheather no is power of 2 or not excludig 0
        arr[ i ] = 1;
    else
        arr[ i ] = 0;
}
for ( int i = 0; i < not; i++ )
{
    if ( arr[ i ] == 1 )
        printf ("YES\n");
    else
        printf ("NO\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that while the word `not` isn't part of stock C, it is an ["alternative token"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_alternative_tokens) for `!` in the C standard, and also reserved in standard C++.  So if you ever might want to compile your C code as C++, or use those alternative tokens (which I personally prefer to the likes of `!` and `&&` and `||`) then you might think about avoiding calling variables "not".  That's all in addition to the fact that it's a confusing name for a variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error because your comparison for `no` to be zero is not a good logical expression for use with `&` operator.

You can get away with this in cases when a value is used by itself, but since `no` is a power of 2 with `0` in the least significant bit, `no & [some-logical-expression]` yields zero.

You can fix this in three ways:

- Use `&&` in place of `&`, i.e. `no && !(no & (no - 1))` or
- Add `!!` in front of `no`, i.e. `!!no & !(no & (no - 1))` or
- Add an explicit comparison to zero, i.e. `no!=0 & !(no & (no - 1))`.

I strongly prefer the first approach.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/aAHCPc)

Answer (score 0):

`&` is bitwise AND. You want logical AND: `no && !(no & (no - 1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my few observation from the code you mentioned.

**Firstly**, What if user given `not` value more than `100` ? It causes **undefined behavior** if `not>100` as you declared `arr` as size of `100`. To avoid this one way is first scan `not` and then create array equal to `not` size. for e.g

```
int not = 0; // no of testcase
scanf ("%d", &not);
int arr[not]; /* create array equal to not size.. */
```

Or create array dynamically like

```
int not = 0; // no of testcase
scanf ("%d", &not);
int *arr = malloc(not * sizeof(*arr)); /* create dynamic array equal to not size.. */
```

**Secondly**, to check given number is power of 2 or not, this `!(no & (no - 1))` is correct but to exclude `zero` i.e if given input `no` is `0` then you shouldn't check `!(no & (no - 1))` this. for this use logical AND `&&` operator. This

```
if ( no & !(no & (no - 1))) { 

}
```

should be

```
if ( no && !(no & (no - 1))) {

}
```